why i receive verification code in spam not in my inbox?
I don't know why I receive this verification code email in spam, not in my inbox.
I receive the email in spam in both localhost and live server. I host my website in DigitalOcean and I use the BREVO smtp server.
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$query,array($_GET['email'],$verificationCode));
$result=sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();    
$mail->Host = 'smtp-relay.brevo.com';                    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 
$mail->Username = $_ENV["LOGINSMTP"];                    
$mail->Password =$_ENV["PASSWORDSMTP"];                             
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';            
$mail->Port = 465;                
$mail->setFrom('mr1.as@gmail.com', 'Gym Manager');
$mail->addAddress($_GET['email'],"");
$mail->addBCC($_GET['email']);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Verification Code';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->Body = `your text`
'
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;background-color: #eee;width: 50%;border-radius: 2%;padding:10px;">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">'.$verificationCode.'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
try{
$mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}


You pretend to send emails from the gmail.com domain, a domain you don't own. You shouldn't do that. You should send them from your own domain, and you can set replyTo() to indicate where you would like to receive responses.

Mail systems do not "know" the difference between spam and regular messages. They use algorithms to scan the content and make decisions based on keyword, parts of web addresses etc. You need to add the source address to your mail system's whitelist.

No, emails need a setFrom(), but that email address should contain a domain that you, or BREVO, control. You cannot send emails on behalf of somebody else. Suppose I would send you an email on behalf of NASA from director@nasa.gov, to invite you to our astronaut program. Don't you think it would be weird if that would be allowed?

Also why are you adding the same email address in the "To" and "Bcc" fields? That doesn't really seem to make any sense.

to be frankly with i don't know how to do it,i already have a domain name and i add it to my brevo account in sender page but i still have the same problem

Email isn't the easiest topic, so it's understandable. Can you create a mailbox for your domain?

As we mentioned earlier, you also need to change the address in setFrom() so it contains a valid email address on the domain you've configured in Brevo. If you don't change that, it will still be trying to send an email pretending to be from a Gmail address it doesn't really have permission to use.

See the duplicate questions (in the blue box above) for a wider discussion of all the things that could potentially go wrong with email sending. Using a professional service like Brevo should alleviate a lot of the issues and enable most things on the email server side to be configured properly for you, but using a From address that your SMTP service doesn't actually have rights to is an obvious problem which you can solve in your PHP code.
